# How to check if the string contains dynamic word that starts with first letter

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out in the string if the word that changes but starts with letter 'F' (C#). The result output from service call is as below:

> Exception_Remote_Call--VNQ DN ERROR CODE found ERROR CODE= F0123,
> ERROR DESCRIPTION= NOT AVAILABLE

In the above string, **F0123** word changes according to the different ERROR CODE. I tried as below but it works for F0123 and does not work if the output is F0111. I would like to find if it starts with 'F'.

```
 var isStartsWithF = s.Contains("F0123");
```

I would really appreciate for the help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you just looking for `ERROR CODE = F` then?

Comment: yes, that is correct. @DavidG

Comment: `s.Contains("ERROR CODE = F")` should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for regular expressions. To make things clearer and easier to spot for future maintainers, I might include the `ERROR CODE =`  as part of the expression:

```
var data = "Exception_Remote_Call--VNQ DN ERROR CODE found ERROR CODE = F0123, ERROR DESCRIPTION= NOT AVAILABLE";   

var exp = new Regex(@"ERROR CODE\s?= (F\d{4,5})");  
var result = exp.Match(data).Groups[1].Value;
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOXOCt

Comment: There is no space after ERROR CODE i.e., ERROR CODE= . In addition, F0123 can be F01234 which is not only 4 after letter 'F'. If it behaves correct with above regex?

Comment: I updated the expression to allow for those items.

Comment: It can be any numbers after F.

Comment: Surely there's a reasonable limit on how long the code can be. the `{4,5}` is a minimum and maximum number of digits, so adjust that part to match your data. You can also use `{2,}`, which will match at least two digits with no maximum.